# Excel VBA - Inputbox not writing data to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having this run at Workbook_Open on a read-only template file that will be reused for new clients. I'm getting an error with the `Name = .Range("L2")` line that says "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" which I'm not entirely sure why it is coming up that way. I'm confident I'm simply overlooking something really simple but any help would be greatly appreciated and if there is a more efficient way of writing this code let me know. I'm eager to learn.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim tB As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DailyWS As Worksheet
Dim Client As String
Dim Name As Range

Set tB = ThisWorkbook
With tB
    Set DailyWS = .Sheets("Daily Tracker")
End With 'tB
With DailyWS
    Name = .Range("L2")
End With 'DailyWS


If Len(Name.Value) = 0 Then
    Client = InputBox("Enter your name :", "Client's Name Please.")
    If Len(Client) = 0 Then 'Checking if Length of name is 0 characters
        MsgBox "Please enter a valid name!", vbCritical
        Goto Tryagain
    End If
    Name.Value = Client
    If Client = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox ("DO NOT CONTINUE!" & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "DO NOT SAVE THIS FILE! " & vbCrLf & _
    "" & vbCrLf & _
    "AT PROMPT PLEASE ENTER A NAME!" & vbCrLf & _
    ""), vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "!! Name Required !!"
    Goto Tryagain
    End If
Else
MsgBox "Not Empty (Test)"
End
End If
end sub
```

Comment: Do what the error says: `Set Name = .Range("L2")`

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I thought I tried that. Apparently not. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to submit that as an answer I'll make it for you. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Name` is a range object and all object need to be set:

```
Set Name = .Range("L2")
```

One note, I would be careful using words that are used in vba.  `Name` is used in many places.  I would use a variable that does not replace an existing command, like `Nme`

Comment: `Name` is actually a *type*, in the Excel object model. I don't think VBA would have any problem telling local variable `Name` from the `Excel.Name` type, given the context in which VBA expects a type name to be specified (e.g. an "AsTypeClause")

Comment: @Mat'sMug I am a hack compared to you, so I will defer to your knowledge.  But, I personally would still avoid it, just because my ocd would require it.

Comment: Pffft.. You're too humble! I'm just good at *making it look like* I know my stuff haha - I actually look up to you, and several other VBA regulars! I'm no MVP! ;-)